# How to use DatabaseInformation, TableInformation and ColumnInformation to determine the column size in hibernate5?

Tags: hibernate

We are planning to upgrade from hibernate3 to hibernate5.4.4

There is following function to determine the column size

public int getColumnLength(String className, String propertyName) throws AMSCheckedException {
        int columnSize;

```
    try {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = (LocalSessionFactoryBean) appContext.getBean("&sessionFactory");
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImpl) appContext.getBean("sessionFactory");


        Metadata metadata = sessionFactoryBean.getMetadataSources().getMetadataBuilder().build();


        PersistentClass pc = sessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration().getClassMapping(className);
        Table t = pc.getTable();
        Column c = t.getColumn(new Column(propertyName));
        Connection connection = sessionFactory.getConnectionProvider().getConnection();



        DatabaseMetadata databaseMetadata = new DatabaseMetadata(connection, sessionFactory.getDialect());

        TableMetadata tableMetadata = databaseMetadata.getTableMetadata(t.getName(), sessionFactory.getSettings().getDefaultSchemaName(),
                                                                        sessionFactory.getSettings().getDefaultCatalogName(), false);

        columnSize = tableMetadata.getColumnMetadata(c.getName()).getColumnSize();

        if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed())
            connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception caught when trying to get column size of " + className + " and property " + propertyName, e);
        throw new AMSCheckedException(AMSExceptionEnum.GENERIC_DB_ACCESS_ERROR, e);
    }

    return columnSize;
}
```

The function currently uses DatabaseMetadata , tableMetaData classes. However DatabaseMetadata  is removed in hibernate5 and tableMetaData is deprecated
As per my understanding, there are classes DatabaseInformation, TableInformation and ColumnInformation to get the column size in hibernate5
However I have not found any concrete example which uses these classes. 
I am looking for concrete example. Could you provide the example.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate instance of

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl

Additional information you can find [here](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl/%3Cinit%3E)